# Meteor UP : Verifying development failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

Im getting following error when trying to deploy my meteor application in AWS.
I have selected ubuntu as my operating system with 30 Gb of HDD. i have attached my mup.json file and snap of cmd response .

[image]

My mup.json is :

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "ec2-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com",
      "username": "ubuntu",
      //"password": "password"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      "pem": "D:/abcUbuntu.pem"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server. 
  // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "Qxmedics",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "D:/abc/version1",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
     "PORT":80,
    "ROOT_URL": "ec2-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

I tried alot... please help me out with this thanks.

Comment: Based on the "must be a url line have you tried adding to http:// (or https if that's what you are using) to the ROOT_URL?

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was making the wait time 45. If the rest is correct, it should confirm and deploy.

```
"deployCheckWaitTime": 45
```

It says there is a problem with your URL so, make sure it is a correct one with http or https.